# Django Server wont launch in Docker-Compose

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am attempting to port a Django project over to Docker-Compose for deployment purposes.

I followed a variety of tutorials online and from my understanding, the only services my App requires are Django and Postgres. Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
db:
  image: postgres:latest
  ports:
    - "5432"
  environment:
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    POSTGRES_USER: postgres
web:
  build: .
  ports:
   - "8000:8000"
  volumes:
   - .:/code
  links:
   - db
  command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I have tested the python command locally in my virtualenv and the server starts, however, when I run 'docker-compose up' in the folder a copy of the application is located in, I get this output:

```
Creating hpr_db_1
Creating hpr_web_1
Attaching to hpr_db_1, hpr_web_1
db_1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
db_1  | This user must also own the server process.
db_1  | 
db_1  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
db_1  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
db_1  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
db_1  | 
db_1  | Data page checksums are disabled.
db_1  | 
db_1  | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
db_1  | creating subdirectories ... ok
db_1  | selecting default max_connections ... 100
db_1  | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
db_1  | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
db_1  | creating configuration files ... ok
db_1  | creating template1 database in /var/lib/postgresql/data/base/1 ... ok
db_1  | initializing pg_authid ... ok
db_1  | initializing dependencies ... ok
web_1 | /usr/local/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py:321: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.utils.importlib will be removed in Django 1.9.
web_1 |   return f(*args, **kwds)
web_1 | 
db_1  | creating system views ... ok
db_1  | loading system objects' descriptions ... ok
db_1  | creating collations ... ok
db_1  | creating conversions ... ok
db_1  | creating dictionaries ... ok
db_1  | setting privileges on built-in objects ... ok
db_1  | creating information schema ... ok
db_1  | loading PL/pgSQL server-side language ... ok
web_1 | /usr/local/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py:321: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.utils.importlib will be removed in Django 1.9.
web_1 |   return f(*args, **kwds)
web_1 | 
db_1  | vacuuming database template1 ... ok
db_1  | copying template1 to template0 ... ok
db_1  | copying template1 to postgres ... ok
db_1  | syncing data to disk ... ok
db_1  | 
db_1  | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db_1  | 
db_1  |     postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/data
db_1  | or
db_1  |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db_1  | 
db_1  | 
db_1  | WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db_1  | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
db_1  | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db_1  | waiting for server to start....LOG:  database system was shut down at 2015-11-06 15:18:39 UTC
db_1  | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1  |  done
db_1  | server started
db_1  | ALTER ROLE
db_1  | 
db_1  | 
db_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
db_1  | 
db_1  | LOG:  received fast shutdown request
db_1  | LOG:  aborting any active transactions
db_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
db_1  | waiting for server to shut down....LOG:  shutting down
db_1  | LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1  |  done
db_1  | server stopped
db_1  | 
db_1  | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db_1  | 
db_1  | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2015-11-06 15:18:41 UTC
db_1  | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

No message about the server starting or anything like that, I know its compiling my code due to the warning messages about deprecation but I am quite stumped here. Can anyone see my error?

**UPDATE:**

Upon closer inspection and changing the port for the DJango server, I find that accessing the webpage returns a "Connection to the Server was reset while the page was loading" error. This indicates that something is being set up on that page. But I still cannot access it. I know Docker-Compose is working as simple Django applications from tutorials work just fine.

Comment: could you insert your dockerfile for your django web app please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you `EXPOSE` the port for the django container?

Comment: This got me looking in the right area so I will mark it as correct, the correct port was not selected in my yml file as defined in my Django projects settings.py's database section

Answer (score 2):

With the .yml file you are creating a build.

You should move the files to deployment environment and keep running the server.

So, when the .yml run successfully, you will have a success build and you will be able to move the files to the deployment environment (where you have a last build running).

Anyway, I don´t recommend execute `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` in the runner., because your runner will be running and it won´t finish (getting the success or failed build).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last sentence, please? Why is it not good to run `python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`? what would you recommend to run instead? I have the problem that when there is a python error, there is no output and the server just does not start.